# setTags-method pushwoosh "device not found"

Tags: android, cordova, pushwoosh

Today I was able to set values for my Tags. Afterwards I deleted it because I wanted to test it, if it would work with String instead List too. I decided to stay by the List-Datatype of the Tag but now, I can´t set the values of the tags anymore. I wrote the setTags-method at the client like this:

pushNotification.setTags({"Tag1":["X"],"Tag2":["A01","A02","A03","A04"]});

But it doesn´t work. I get this error:

01-21 13:45:52.312: W/PushWoosh: NetworkUtils(2680): PushWooshResult: {"status_code":210,"status_message":"Device not found","response":null}

Also if I register in the app it takes over an hour, that I get push notifications again. So this could be the problem, but I don`t know what I should do.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

We are aware of this issue and our team is working hard to fix this. We are very sorry for the inconvenience. This should be resolved today or tomorrow.

Pushwoosh team.

Comment: Hi! Same here, still getting "Device not found", Jan. 25th.